# What is the python 3 equivalence of python 2 command - print("-")*80?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I need to find the equivalence of Python 3 command for Python 2 `print('-')*80`. I try to run `print('-')*80` in Python 3, but got an error message.

Comment: I get "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType and 'int'

Comment: Background reading: https://realpython.com/python-print/#print-was-a-statement-in-python-2. Very regrettable behavior in Python2, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

It should be following .

```
print('-'*80)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just multiply whatever you want to display with the number of times you want to display it, hence, `'-'*80`
 and since python 3 uses parenthesis syntax for printing `print('Hello World')`, Hence,

```
print('-'*80)
```

should get you the required output.